# Unable to get the InnerHtml of the editor div of Bootstrap WYSIWYG rich text editor in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using **[Bootstrap WYSIWYG rich text editor](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/)** for making HTML email templates. This works fine when I check in the browser.

I can get the HTML contents of the editor div in JQuery by `$("#editor").html();`

I gave the editor div a runat="server" attribute in order to get the HTML content in the server side. But I am not able to get the editor div's HTML content in the server side.

I tried to assign the HTML content to a hidden field and to access it in server side but still got no success :(

Any suggestions ???

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html for the editor element?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the value of a hidden field and then accessing the hidden field from server side.

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBody" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<script>
    function GetEmailID() {
        var emailIDs = $(".search-choice span").text();
        var bodyHtml = $("#editor").html();

        $("#hdnBody").val(bodyHtml);
        $("#hdnEmailIds").val(values);           

    }
</script>
```

Then in serverside

```
 string body = hdnBody.Value;
```

Thanks